# objects inside Ext.tab.Panel

Tags: sencha-touch-2

I am writing simple apps with Sencha Touch 2. I see that the basic object in app/view/Main.js is Ext.tab.Panel.

What other Ext objects can be embedded directly into Ext.tab.Panel? Where can I look up this information?

Answer (score 0):

From the Sencha Touch 2.3.1 docs, `Ext.tab.Panel` section:

http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel

> Tab Panels are a great way to allow the user to switch between several
>   pages that are all full screen. Each Component in the Tab Panel gets
>   its own Tab, which shows the Component when tapped on. Tabs can be
>   positioned at the top or the bottom of the Tab Panel, and can
>   optionally accept title and icon configurations.

Basically, you can put any view class which is subclass of `Ext.Container` inside a tab panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can put any view you want.You can even put another container inside a container

Have a look at sencha touch docs.

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/guide/views